# Increment a variable while Inserting multiple rows Stored Procedure

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I am trying to increment a variable while inserting multiple rows.

Here is my last attempt.

```
DECLARE @i  int
Set @i=0
Insert into winners (ContestantID, DrawingID, SlotNumber) 
SELECT TOP (@Total) ID, @DrawingID, @i + 1  FROM Contestants 
where Drawingid=@DrawingID ORDER BY NEWID()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the ROW_NUMBER function:

```
INSERT INTO winners (ContestantID
    , DrawingID
    , SlotNumber) 
SELECT TOP (@Total) ID
    , @DrawingID
    , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID)  
FROM Contestants 
WHERE Drawingid = @DrawingID
ORDER BY NEWID()
```

Comment: That works great if starting at 1 but what if I want to start at say 220 and increment by 1?

Comment: Add 219 to the ROW_NUMBER? It returns a BIGINT that you can do arithmetic on.

Comment: Tried that but t threw  syntax error  ROW_NUMBER() + @260

Comment: Is @260 a variable you've declared? And the ROW_NUMBER() function requires an OVER clause.

Comment: Yes, its an int variable with a value

Comment: This worked, ROW_NUMBER()  OVER (ORDER BY NEWID())  + @260 THANK U!